# Cannot connect - invalid settings

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using windows 10 & am having all kinds of trouble with Xampp/MySql/PhpMyAdmin, problems which I did not get on Windows 7.

So basically I made a Laravel website at work where I still use windows 7, so the password for the MySQL database works fine there.

However when I try to login on my website at home (windows 10) I get the 'using password NO' error... So to rectify this error I used the Xampp shell and executed this command: `mysqladmin --user=root password "newpassword"` which then allowed me to use any database dependent functions on my website that previously did not work, but now when I try to get onto localhost/phpmyadmin I am getting the error 'Cannot connect - invalid settings'.

So in summary it's either I can

A. get on phpmyadmin fine but none of the database dependent features of my Laravel site work.

B. The database features all work but I can't access phpmyadmin anymore.

Can anyone advise on how I can get both things to work?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're using two machines, correct?

Then it will be your configuration that's different from the other.

Reinstall it on the Windows 10 machine and replicate what you've done on the other machine (copy the xampp files over like the php.ini and any other configuration file).

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Basically I had to change my .env file in Laravel to take no password because copying the files didn't solve the password issue, however I can now use my laravel site and access phpmyadmin!

One strange thing is that when going on phpmyadmin it asks me to enter a password which it has not done before & the password I use in work doesn't work, however I can simply enter 'root' username and no password and it lets me in. Either way, the bottom line is my problem is more or less solved, thanks so much!