# Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I installed new `Laravel` project and connected that to my database via `.env` file using the following setup.

```
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root.
```

Now when I type `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gives me

> Cannot connect: invalid settings
>
> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
>
> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170538/phpmyadmin-cannot-connect-invalid-settings), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928818/cannot-connect-invalid-settings) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170538/phpmyadmin-cannot-connect-invalid-settings) but nothing is working.

`config.inc.php` has the following :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root'
```

I don't want to `uninstall` the old `xampp` and install new one , because the old contain really important `databases`

Please help me, what should I do ?

Comment: Sidenote: you can always dump your databases and reimport them again on a fresh installation

Comment: hi @LelioFaieta, thanks for the comment, how can I do that ? I can't even access my databases

Comment: You can use phpmyadmin or MySQL workbench to access it

Comment: but when I type `localhost/phpmyadmin` it gives me this error, how can I access it ? I'm confused @LelioFaieta

Comment: Change the host in phpmyadm config file from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: it's already `127.0.0.1`

Comment: what could be the problem ? @LelioFaieta